# How do i loop over my JSP response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jsp

jquery looks like this

```
    $.post('JSP/processForm.jsp', $("#Form").serialize(),
          function(data){
          //I want to iterate through every line in the data object returned here.

   });
```

I searched and tried:

```
$.each($(data), function(key, value) {
      alert(value);
});
```

But that did not work. I understand the response needs to be encoded into a jQuery object first.

```
$(data)
```

But i just can't seem to find a way to iterate through every line. The jsp code is simply:

```
out.println("Test");
out.println("Test Email");
out.println("Test CellPhone");
out.println("305-777-5587");
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is going to get just a blob of text; a string, that is.  Your JSP code is doing nothing to make it be organized as anything else.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of that. An alternative is to use JSON to encode the data to an array structure which would allow me to loop over it but i was just wondering if there was a way i could do the equivalent of that without having to use JSON.

Comment: Try `alert(data)` to check the response string, `println` should add a `\n` character to the end of each line at least. You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `data` and iterate over it.

Comment: Define "does not work"... split on newlines if you want to iterate over a string delimited newlines.

Comment: It isn't the very best solution and won't work properly if you output a text with linebreaks, but with the current OP setup there is no other way around. JSON is a probably better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

- Your jsp is likely being rendered and returned with a header that suggests it's html content. You are (somewhat arbitrarily) deciding that each new line of text represents a new piece of data.
- jQuery each documentation shows it only works on a collection, so jQuery wrapping your object isn't necessary. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) However, jQuery has no method by which to parse your returned html into a javascript collection object.
- If you are truly trying to end up with a javascript structured data object, you may consider sending your output as JSON (javascript object notation). From what I've seen, it seems more fitting in this case.

If you did want to continue this way, you'd need to write some javascript to split your response html at the new line. It would likely look like this (you may need to play around with it)

```
var myData = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
```

Comment: My bad it was working i was making a silly mistake. Thanks a lot!